# Trying to declare class in androidmanifest

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to declare my activity in my AndroidManifest.xml. It doesn't work because it says `com.vakantielanden.quizapp.QuizResultaatFrankrijk is not public`

When I try to make my class public it gives the following error: `Class 'QuizResultaatFrankrijk' is public, should be declared in a file name 'QuizResultaatFrankrijk.java'`

So what should I do now to fix this. Thanks in advance!

This is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.vakantielanden.quizapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/applogo"
    android:label="VakantielandenQuiz"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/applogo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".KeuzeActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".QuizActivityFrankrijk"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".QuizActivitySpanje"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".QuizActivityItalie"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".QuizActivityDuitsland"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".QuizActivityNoorwegen"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".QuizActivityZweden"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".HighscoreActivity"></activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

</application>


</manifest>
```

And this is the java code in question:

```
class QuizResultaatFrankrijk extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView mFinalScoreFrankrijk;
Button mHomeButtonFrankrijk;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result_quiz);

    mFinalScoreFrankrijk = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreresultaat);
    mHomeButtonFrankrijk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.homepageknop);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int score = bundle.getInt("finalScoreFrankrijk");

    mFinalScoreFrankrijk.setText( + score + "");


    mHomeButtonFrankrijk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(QuizResultaatFrankrijk.this, 
HomeActivity.class));
            QuizResultaatFrankrijk.this.finish();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Post your manifest, and the java file in question. It sounds like its something simple

Comment: I know it's not related to your question and idk what you try to achieve but it seems that you have an Activity per language. Maybe you can manage it differently using only one Activity and the user choose the language (or it's automatically based on the device's language). In this last scenario the only thing you have to do is to create a string.xml file for each supported languages, containing the translations.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to make an `Activity` class, that class should be public also the name of the file should resemble the `Activity` name.

So you might have changed the `Activity` name but you have not changed the file which that activity belongs So Examples:
If activity is `MainActivity` then file name is `MainActivity.java`
If activity name is `QuizResultaatFrankrijk`
then the file name should be `QuizResultaatFrankrijk.java`

Check your code and solve it!

Answer (score 0):

Copy this part of the code:

```
TextView mFinalScoreFrankrijk;
Button mHomeButtonFrankrijk;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result_quiz);

    mFinalScoreFrankrijk = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreresultaat);
    mHomeButtonFrankrijk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.homepageknop);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int score = bundle.getInt("finalScoreFrankrijk");

    mFinalScoreFrankrijk.setText( + score + "");


    mHomeButtonFrankrijk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(QuizResultaatFrankrijk.this, 
HomeActivity.class));
            QuizResultaatFrankrijk.this.finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Delete the file, create it again and paste your code again.